# Using wp_editor() when not logged stopped working

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, tinymce, editor

I've build myself a custom page template. Within this template I'm using the `wp_editor()` function. Sadly, when I logout now from my wp site and go now to the page I want to see, I'm getting an error in my console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
```

When I log back in, everything works quite fine. I've also tried to enqueue the editor script if a user isn't logged in this way:

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-tinymce' );
}
```

But this don't solved my issue. I've cleaned the cache every time and restarted the server.

So does anyone has an idea how I can get the `wp_editor()` function runnning with non-logged-in users?

Comment: Try using [`wp_enqueue_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_editor/)?

Comment: @SallyCJ Tried it but the error is still there.